# Magento - Add a static block to the left column

Tags: magento

How would I go about adding a static block on my left column on the category pages?

I would like the static block to go underneath the main column so that it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dR5W.jpg

Thank-you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override catalog.xml layout file in your template.

in  and

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="cms/block" name="block-name">
          <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_id</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>

<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="cms/block" name="block-name">
          <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_id</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Comment: Include exactly what Kandarp said, however, please do this in a local.xml file.  If you need to learn how to use one,  I will gladly explain.